# Terrarium Compatibility: Millipedes with Carnivorous Plants?

Tags: botany, ecology, ecosystem, community-ecology, arthropod

I have a child that loves his large millipedes (Desert Millipedes) and Venus Fly Traps.  He's also been wanting to get some Sundew Savages.  Given this little collection and his real enjoyment of terrariums, we're curious if we could consolidate his millipedes into a terrarium with these carnivorous plants without causing harm to either of them.

We keep the millipedes fed well with decomposing plant material, but weren't sure if they'd go wild after the fresh plants... and then of course if they would try to do that, could these plants harm the millipedes?

In the end I fear there will be some problems here and wanted to check to see if anyone knows about this compatibility before we dive in and have our hopes dashed.

Comment: Millipedes eat decomposing material, not fresh. Carnivorous plants eat very small things like flies, not millipedes. They digest their food using enzymes, just like you and I do - they're not poisonous. You're fine.